# successive $(document).on('click', ... statements failing after first

Tags: jquery

I have a comment feature on my site. Two buttons, one to upvote and one to downvote. The comments are dynamically created after the page has loaded, so the code to handle clicks is...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).off().on("click", ".videonotes_note_feedback_useful_no",  function() { videonotes_addRating($(this).parent().data('id'), -1); });
    $(document).off().on("click", ".videonotes_note_feedback_useful_yes",  function() { videonotes_addRating($(this).parent().data('id'), +1); });
});
```

where the addRating function is a simple:

```
function videonotes_addRating(feedback_id, value) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

for the time being.

The problem is that the second `$(document).off().on("click",` **always** does nothing - so if I put the -1 first then the console outputs minus one and does nothing when I click the other. If I reverse them in the code the console outputs +1.

Is there any known reason why this should be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the off function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".videonotes_note_feedback_useful_no",  function() { videonotes_addRating($(this).parent().data('id'), -1); });
    $(document).on("click", ".videonotes_note_feedback_useful_yes",  function() { videonotes_addRating($(this).parent().data('id'), +1); });
});
```

Comment: Which works, but I put the off() in to prevent multiple clicks - before you might click it and it would fire 3-5 times... maybe I should use one instead...

Comment: Although actually the problem might be something else - thanks, your answer solved this problem.. its just another issue it seems :(